# How to convert hash Set into array using toArray() if the method toArray is not specified?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

Looking at the java api for java collections framework, I could not find toArray() method in HashSet, there is toArray() method in abstract class Set.

```
class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Set x = new HashSet();
        x.add(4);
        //ArrayList<Integer> y = x.toArray(); this does not work !
        int[] y = x.toArray();//this does not work!

        System.out.println(x.toArray());//this gives some weird stuff printed : Ljava.lang.Object;@106d69c
    }
}
```

How do I convert hashset into array if there is no toArray() specified?

Comment: well, the toArray returns an `Object[]`, just printing that is giving you the typical java output if the toString is not properly overwritten. And an `Object[]` is not implicitly convertible to `int[]`.

Comment: @luk2302 exactly. This is what i have written in my answer but its downvoted. I am not sure whats the issue in answer. Can anyone explain please so that i can improve

Comment: @MSach probably because you only explain the printed output, not why the first line does not work nor what would be the proper way - but that is of course only a guess

Comment: Thanks luk. i did not pay attention that there is one more question. Will explain that too

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Of course `HashSet` implements `toArray`. It must implement it, since it implements the `Set` interface, which specifies this method. The actual implementation is in `AbstractCollection` which is the super class of `AbstractSet` which is the super class of `HashSet`.

First of all, you shouldn't use raw types.

Use :

```
Set<Integer> x = new HashSet<>();
x.add(4);
```

Then convert to array :

```
Integer[] arr = x.toArray(new Integer[x.size()]);
```

Using `x.toArray()` would give you an `Object[]`.

Comment: yes, i just noticed that you can add string, int , char etc to unspecified hashSet!

Comment: @ERJAN Yeah that's because it then uses the `Object` class, and the boxed versions of those primitives extend `Object`.

Comment: also this is to convert  to Integer[] array, if developer is interested to convert to int[] then refer to my solution below.


https://stackoverflow.com/a/74862173/17903735

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you declare the generic for the `HashSet`

```
Set<Integer> x = new HashSet<>();
```

And convert it to an array like so:

```
int[] y = new int[x.size()];
int c = 0;
for(int x : x) y[c++] = x;
```

Answer (score 3):

**First Line**

> ArrayList y = x.toArray(); this does not work !

First of all you used    `Set x = new HashSet();` i.e raw type . Compiler does not know that s it going to contain integer object but with above line on left hand side you are saying its going to be arraylist of integer where actually its an array

**Second line**

> int[] y = x.toArray();//this does not work!

with above line on left hand side you are saying its going to be array of integer where actually its an array of objects

**This will work**

```
Object[] y = x.toArray();
```

But this is not the right way . You should not use raw types

```
 Set<Integer> x = new HashSet<>();
 Integer[] intArray= x.toArray(new Integer[x.size()]);
```

> System.out.println(x.toArray());//this gives some weird stuff printed
>   : Ljava.lang.Object;@106d69c

Its printing   [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) representation of array object . Thats why you are seeing it as `Ljava.lang.Object;@106d69c`

If you want to print each element , iterate over it and then print it.

Comment: Downvoter it will be helpful to know whats wrong here ? I am not getting whats the issue in the answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you originally wanted to create an ArrayList rather than a simple Array. So, try this!

```
class Ideone 
{
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception   
        {
            Set x = new HashSet();
            x.add(4);
            ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>(x);
            System.out.println(y);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparison in JDK 7 sorting a small map, using `TreeSet`, `ArrayList` and `Array`:

```
long start  = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){ 
   TreeSet a   = new TreeSet(payloads.keySet());                           
} 
System.out.println("TreeSet: "    + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + " ms.");
start       = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){ 
   ArrayList a = new ArrayList(payloads.keySet()); 
   Collections.sort(a);    
} 
System.out.println("ArrayList: "  + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + " ms.");
start       = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){ 
   String[] a = payloads.keySet().toArray(new String[payloads.size()]); 
   Arrays.sort(a);    
} 
System.out.println("Array: "  + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + " ms.");
```

Yields:

> TreeSet: 1527 ms.
>   ArrayList: 943 ms.
>   Array: 485 ms.

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate through the loop and store the values into the array.

```
int[] answer = new int[set1.size()];
int i = 0;
for (int num : set1) {
      answer[i++] = num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert a hashset to arraylist then to arrays int[]. this approach is good if u want to dynamically convert it back to array.

this would be a one-liner solution.

```
Set<Integer> my_set = new HashSet<>();
my_set.add(4);

int[] result = new ArrayList<>(my_set).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); // [4]
```